# Can we not pass pipe chain output into linear model lm() dot placeholder?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lm, magrittr

I wanted to know how to pass the output of pipe operation directly into `lm()`.

For example, I can pass this following `yay` vector into `lm()` directly.

```r
set.seed(40)
yay = c(rnorm(15), exp(rnorm(15)), runif(20, min = -3, max = 0))
lm(yay~1)

#> Call:
#> lm(formula = yay ~ 1)

#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  
#>    -0.09522
```

But when I tried something like this, it threw an error.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

data("penguins")

filter_penguins <- penguins %>% filter(species == "Adelie") 

filter_penguins %>% 
  filter(island == "Torgersen") %>% 
  select(bill_length_mm) %>%
  pull() %>% 
  lm(. ~ 1)

#> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula
```

I have also tried to save the `pull()` output into object and later feed it into `lm()`, it works. But why the dot placeholder doesnot work this way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `filter_penguins %>% filter(island == "Torgersen") %>% lm(bill_length_mm ~ 1, data=.)`.  By default the pipe uses the object to its left as the first argument to the function on its right.  When the function needs something different, use a dot (`.`) to indicate where the object should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issu is that `lm()` inside a pipeline consider the data given as `formula` argument. Therefore, the data is missplaced. Try:

```
filter_penguins %>% 
  filter(island == "Torgersen") %>% 
  select(bill_length_mm) %>%
  lm(data = ., pull(.) ~ 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I realise that I misread the question, and thought OP wanted to pass in a variable name as part of a formula, rather than pass in the dataset itself. I'll leave this post in for the former reason, anyway.

It won't work because the first argument to `lm` will be whatever is piped in, which is not a proper formula (as the error suggests).

Using your example, and pretending that the piped value is "var", then

```
"var" %>% 
    lm(. ~ 1)
```

would be evaluated as

```
lm(formula = "var", . ~ 1)
```

so the `. ~ 1` portion isn't part of the formula argument. You could construct the formula with `paste0` or similar, though. For example, this would work:

```
"mpg" %>%
    paste0(" ~ .") %>%
    lm(data = mtcars)
```